# networkx line vertices as nodes

Tags: python, shapefile, topology, networkx

I read shapefile and converts it into a `Graph` using `networkx` and `momepy` as per documentation. `networkx` converts endpoints as nodes and the line as the edge, and disregard the vertices within the line. is there anyway to account for thesse vertices as the `Graph`'s nodes? (perhaps manipulation using `geopandas`?)

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Making each vertex of a line a node in the graph would make your graph huge.  It would also provide no extra junctions so not changing the topology of the network?

Comment: I want to preserve the geometry. converting it straight to graph reduces the geometry, and when I map the shortest path result in Qgis it's just a straight line. I want it go along the initial shapefile.  @Hornbydd

Comment: Hmmm, I don't use QGIS but I would explore the manual for networkx because displaying the result of a network trace along the original geometry (what you want to do) is what everyone else on the planet wants to do to, including me. To just show the results on the abstracted logical network is unhelpful so I'm guessing networkx could either return it along the original geometry or provide the row ids for you to build up the geometry you want to display. This sounds to me you need to spend some quality time with the help file, unless it _really cannot_ return the trace geometry?

Comment: Hi @Hornbydd , seems like BERA's suggestion solves the issue; plus QGIS has the ```explode lines``` tool. However, this tool is not available yet in ```geopandas``` and therefore seems like I have to code it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are digging yourself a very deep hole as your approach to using vertices of lines as nodes in a graph is not scalable. You may have polylines that have been densified and I've no idea how it will treat Bezier curves if they are within your dataset?

Look at this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62001044/shortest-route-when-converted-to-linestring-misses-the-path-in-osmnx) they take the result of a trace and build up the polyline, which was what I suggested in the comments above. This won't change the underlying complexity of your network which you will do if you split by segments.

Comment: sigh, you are right. I ended up with emulating networkx like ```pgrouting``` algorithm. this is way more efficient, as you have said. thanks.

Comment: :) You are now a wiser person for it...